# Unable to get a token from different Angular project url on a cors enabled .net API

Tags: .net, angular, api, oauth-2.0, token

I am able to receive the token with postman but the code gives me an error:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    };
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', username);
    formData.append('password', password);
    formData.append('grant_type', 'password');

    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}token`, formData, httpOptions)
      .pipe(map(user => this.setSession(user)));
  }

  private setSession(authResult) {
    const expiresAt = moment().add(authResult.expiresIn, 'second');

    localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    localStorage.setItem("expires_at", JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf()));
  }
}
```

My headers:

> :authority: localhost:44302 :method: POST :path: /api/token :scheme:
>   https accept: application/json, text/plain, */* accept-encoding: gzip,
>   deflate, br accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9 content-length: 372
>   content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded origin:
>   https://localhost:44354 referer: https://localhost:44354/login
>   sec-fetch-dest: empty sec-fetch-mode: cors sec-fetch-site: same-site
>   user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163
>   Safari/537.36

My Error:

```
ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "https://localhost:44302/api/token", ok: false, …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
status: 400
statusText: "OK"
url: "https://localhost:44302/api/token"
ok: false
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
message: "Http failure response for https://localhost:44302/api/token: 400 OK"
error: {error: "unsupported_grant_type"}
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

API Token section:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/LogOff"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5.0),
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow  
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/API/Token"),
            Provider = new OAuthAppProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true //Don't do this in production ONLY FOR DEVELOPING: ALLOW INSECURE HTTP!  
        };

        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);  
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)); 
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    };
    const formData = 'grant_type=password&username=' + encodeURIComponent(username) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(password);

    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}token`, formData, httpOptions)
      .pipe(map(user => this.setSession(user)));
  }
```